# How to show that $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt \rightarrow \infty $ for $x \rightarrow \infty$ if $f(t) = e^{t^2}$

Tags: integration

How do I show that $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt \rightarrow \infty $ for $x \rightarrow \infty$ if $f(t) = e^{t^2}$? I know that $f(t)$ is an increasing function and as $x \rightarrow \infty$ it is pretty clear to me that $F(x) \rightarrow \infty$ for $x \rightarrow \infty $ but is this argumentation enough? Or what do I have to do to prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(t)\geq f(0)=1$ so that:$$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\geq\int_0^xdt=x$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $e^t\geq t+1$ for any real $t$.

Comment: $e^t \ge 1$ for $t \ge 0$ would already be sufficient here.

Answer (score 2):

$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}dt\ge \int_{0}^{x}1dt=x$, since $e^{t^2} \ge 1$ for $t  \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$F(x) = \int_0^x e^{t^2}dt \geq  \int_0^x t^2dt
=x^3/3.$
One can easily observe that $F(x)$ tends to infinity as $ x $ tends to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be a bit more general:

Let $f:[0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $L:=\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) \in (\mathbb{R}\setminus{0})\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$. Then $\int_0^{+\infty} f$ is not convergent.

Here is a proof: WLOG assume that $L>0$. Pick a real number $
0<a<L$. The limit guarentees that $\exists y \in \mathbb{R}_+$ so that $f(x)>a \forall x >y$. This means that
$$\int_0^x f=\int_0^y f + \int_y^x f \geqslant \int_0^y f + \int_y^x a=\int_0^y f + a(x-y)$$
The first term is a real number, independent of $x$, while the second one goes to $+\infty$, which implies that the improper Riemann-integral is not convergent.